# Why is my iPad unable to determine location with some hotspots?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi, android

[image]If its connected through a connected chain looking hotspot, it can determine my location? What’s the reason? Also I’ve searched and found out that the connected chain looking hotspot is only created through apple or xiaomi device. Why is it so, and how can I create that kind of hotspot through other android device?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected chain"? Generally, most Android devices can create a mobile hotspot if the cellular service allows it. And your iPad should be able to connect to the android mobile hotspot through Wifi.

Comment: I meant the symbol when iphone’s or xiaomi’s mobile hotspot is connected which is different symbol than a android mobile hotspot.

Comment: According to Apple, the ["connected chain" symbol](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207354) appears on iOS to show that you have connected to the internet through a Personal Hotspot of another **iOS device**. But yes, you are right that it also sometimes appears when connecting with a non-ios hotspot device too (like Xiaomi).

Comment: Yeah, and is there any special function it can do and not the other hotspots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your iPad doesn't have GPS hardware (available only with cellular models), iOS on it uses an online geolocation service to try determine the location.

One of the ways the geolocation services tries to do this is by trying to determine the location of the wifi you have connected to. This works well only if the location of wifi is already known - like cell phone towers, or public wifi hotspots, or wifi routers whose location is already known because of other devices (with GPS) that have connected to it etc. Generally, if you are connected to a cellular data, some cellular providers can also provide limited GPS data but this is also not consistent.

In other words, if your device doesn't have built-in hardware for GPS, trying to determine your position through other means are somewhat unreliable. And that is what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you, also I would like to ask if there’s any specific function provided if we connect the ipad wifi to iphone’s hospot different than a android’s hotspot.

Comment: Yes, iOS does provide an extra feature called [Instant Hotspot](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT209459) that only works with other Apple devices.